# How to use system.d service with SDKMan

Tags: java, nexus, systemd, nexus3, sdkman

I am trying to install Sonatype Nexus 3 as a service via system.d and it fails due to INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME not being set (or at least, so claims `systemctl`). I use SDKMan! (http://sdkman.io) to manage my Java installation. I am following the Sonatype directions at https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation/run-as-a-service .

I can run it as the user specified in `run_as_user` in a bash shell with no difficulties.

How do I make the java home environment variable provided by SDKman visible to system.d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL:DR; to resolve, add an `Environment` section to the system.d service file:

```
[Service]
Environment="INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME=/home/nexus/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/"
```

Long-form answer:

As of this writing, the Sonatype documents say to use the following file as your `/etc/systemd/system/nexus.service` file, which works great if you installed java to your service user via the system distribution (ensuring your distro's java home is managed by the system). That doesn't work to resolve my question:

```
[Unit]
Description=nexus service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
LimitNOFILE=65536
ExecStart=/opt/nexus/bin/nexus start
ExecStop=/opt/nexus/bin/nexus stop
User=nexus
Restart=on-abort
TimeoutSec=600

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To resolve, you must add the Environment variable to the system.d service file (with `your_user` replaced by the user you are running `nexus` as, and `/opt/nexus` being replaced by your nexus install location):

```
[Unit]
Description=nexus service
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment="INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME=/home/your_user/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/"
Type=forking
LimitNOFILE=65536
ExecStart=/opt/nexus/bin/nexus start
ExecStop=/opt/nexus/bin/nexus stop
User=your_user
Restart=on-abort
TimeoutSec=600

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```